# Can value after get "?" store in database just by loading the page?

Tags: php, mysql, google-analytics

If user open domain.com/article?username=bob then a new row get insert in database table under usernames with the value bob just by loading the page, is it possible ? if yes then how i can achieve this ?

Just like google analytics, if you have analytics on and open domain.com/article?utm_campaign=bob then google analytics store value for bob in their database including visitor's information just on loading the page.

Please pardon my English, Thanks

Comment: we can't work with this; post your codes.

Comment: *"Please pardon my English"* - Your English isn't in question, it's the lack of code.

Comment: Yes, you could do that. In your base controller you could have it process the event then or you could parse your access logs, or you could make something on each page the tracks access. There are a number of ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have previously created and connected to a database. Use PHP's [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable to return an array of all parameters in the URL.

Using your example URL: domain.com/article?username=bob

```
<?php
    // (connect to database here)

    $username = $_GET['username']; // bob
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('".$username."')";

    // (execute $sql variable here)
?>
```

Comment: @YuJiaao There are absolutely more steps that could have been added. I took the assumption that the $_GET variable was the solution being looked for, and not the entire function, given the users previously asked questions.

Comment: Perfect what i were looking for, can you please hint me how to make it secure or anti sql injection ?

Answer (score 0):

Although you have not posted you codes here, i believe you should use cookies and sessions to achieve what you want.
Cookies are used to save users data, then transmitted back to server

Comment: No, that's a serious misunderstanding of what cookies are used for…